# ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoModelForImageCaptioning' from 'transformers'

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm trying to fine-tune a hugging face pre-trained model. This is my imports code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForImageCaptioning, Trainer
import transformers
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoModelForImageCaptioning' from 'transformers' (/Users/abdulmajeed/Desktop/hfAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py)
```

I'm using python 3.11.5 and I have made sure I have latest version of transformers installed.

Should I be using a specific version of transformers? Or have they changed the name for AutoModelForImageCaptioning to something else?